# Rails : From form_for to form_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For one of my projects i'm using https://github.com/rsantamaria/papercrop in addition to paperclip to crop pictures before upload.

It is said in the readme to do :

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
<%= f.cropbox :avatar %>
<%= f.crop_preview :avatar %>
<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

The issue is that my form i need to adapt those function to is a form_tag.
I usually always manage to navigate between the two as needed but since my form is in my application layout ( needs to be there to be on all pages) i don't really use a controller for it but instead form_tag my_post_route_path :

```
<%= form_tag products_path, multipart: true do %>
name
<%= text_field_tag(:name) %>
</br>description
<%= text_field_tag(:description) %>
</br>image
</br><%= file_field_tag "image" %>
<%= submit_tag("create product") %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to know two things :

-How do you translate the methods from f.cropbox etc. to Form tag syntax ? i really don't see a way.
I've tried cropbox_tag but it didn't work ( and i didn't make any sens anyway)

-My second question is kind of different but where , when i have a form that need to pop up on all pages ( i'm using a jquery dialog to make it pop up and a button in the navbar ), should it be placed ? is the fact that i've put it in my application_view completely wrong , i've placed it cause the form is only for logged in users ?

Thanks to anyone who tries to help!

Comment: for your second question, create a new thread.

Comment: as a new question on SO.